# Android: How to remove the Activity Title Bar?

Tags: java, android

I am wanting to get rid of the Activity Title Bar as it is annoying to have. However, I do not want to have a fullscreen activity.I have tried just adding `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` to activity and `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` to the manifest file, but I keep getting the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

If it asked you use Appcompat theme - use appcompat theme

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` and use the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // remove notification bar 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to [set flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29) to an activty window:

For example you can achieve your propose writing this on the onCreate method of your activity.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `onCreate`

```
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

In your style.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
         <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to go:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

put it in your onCreate method and you'll never see the Action Bar.

Comment: Hiding it programmatically means that it will still be shown while the activity is started (as at that point it is only going off the theme information).

Comment: If you hide it in onCreate it never gets displayed.

Comment: That is not true if your application `onCreate()` takes any length of time - you will get a theme provided placeholder before your activity's `onCreate()` runs and you'll see the action bar in that placeholder.