# Android: How should I remove the Activity Title Bar?

Tags: java, android

I am wanting to get rid of the Activity Title Bar as it is annoying to have.

All of the previous help I have received has not worked :(. Here is the original post. 
[Android: How to remove the Activity Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355552/android-how-to-remove-the-activity-title-bar)

Here is the code and xml file.

```
package com.example.ryanfolz.gridgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Context ctx;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ctx = this;
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoChooseGame = new Intent(ctx, WhichGameActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(gotoChooseGame);

        }
    });
    Button optionsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.options_button);
    optionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoChooseGame = new Intent(ctx, WhichGameActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(gotoChooseGame);

        }
    });






}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
android:background="#ff000000">

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="@string/play"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="#fffff6f9"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:text="@string/options"
    android:id="@+id/options_button"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start_button"
    android:background="#fffff6f9"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: what does your manifest file look like for that activity?

Comment: Doesn't want action bar, uses compatibility class that adds action bar for older API levels.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration specifically asks for an action bar

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

try

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: No. This is to signify that it is an appcompat activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your Manifest file, the activity you don't want to have the actionbar in has:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

Comment: I get the error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." whenever I attempt to do that.

Comment: Well you need to use the theme that the app is using. Please edit your question and post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` programmatically..this should be your first line

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use ActionBarActivity ,You don't need an action bar just extend Activity

Put this code before setcontentview :

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Use Theme.AppCompat.Light for your activity theme

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do.
1) You can apply theme of `No-Title-Bar` in your Manifest file under `<application>` tag if you want the whole application without action/title bar like:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"> 

         // your all activities.....

</application>
```

2) You can apply theme to particular activity in which you don't want to show title/action bar like:

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> 

             <activity name="com.yourpackage.activity_name" 
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
             </activity>

    </application>
```